# jQuery reference <object>

Tags: jquery, object, video

I'm having trouble trouble referencing my `<object>`

This is what I have :

```
<div id="videoHolder1" style="display: none;">
  <object id="video1" data="http://vimeo.com/..." type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="data" value="http://vimeo.com/..." />
    <param name="src" value="http://vimeo.com/..." />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
  </object>
</div>
```

I've tried these :

```
alert($(".video1 embed").attr('src') );        // undefined 
alert($("#video1").attr('src') );              // undefined
alert( $("#video1" ).get(0).attr('src') );     // undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want the value of the `<param>` element with name="src"?

```
// /-------------- Select tag with id=video1
// |       /------ Select child param tag
// |       |    /- Filter to tags with a "name" attribute with value "src"  
// |       |    |  
$("#video1 param[name=src]").attr("value") // return value of "value" attribute
```